# ag-grid noRowsOverlay disappears after rowData update

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I need to show a no results message when there are no matching records for applied filters.
I have achieved this with below code

```
<AgGridReact
  onFilterChanged={({ api }) => {
    if (api.getDisplayedRowCount()) {
      api.hideOverlay();
    } else {
      api.showNoRowsOverlay();
    }
  }}
/>
```

However I have fetch call at every 20 sec interval which updates the rowData. This rowData update makes the noRowsOverlay disappear.
I need the overlay to always stay as long as there are no rows displayed in the grid.

How do I handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

Using `onModelUpdated` instead of `onFilterChanged` solved my problem.